# Get the Category Name instead of ID from WP-API

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, wp-api

I'm trying to get the category **name** instead of the **ID** from the WP REST API for my Custom Post Type. Some articles about endpoint modification gave me some ideas on how to solve it, but unfortunately i'm not getting it to work. This is my Code (* removed irrelevant code at some lines):

**CUSTOM POST TYPE**

```
<?php
  add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_projects' );
        function portfolio_projects() {
          $labels = array([...]);

          $args = array(
             [...]
              'show_in_rest'          => true,
              'rest_base'             => 'projects',
              'rest_controller_class' => 'Category_Data',
              'supports'              => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
              'taxonomies'            => array('post_tag', 'category')
          );

          register_post_type( 'project', $args );
      }
```

**CONTROLLER CLASS**

```
<?php
/**
 * Category data
 */
class Category_Data extends WP_REST_Posts_Controller
{

    public function init()
    {
        add_action('rest_api_init', array(
            $this,
            'add_category_data'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Add the category data
     */
    public function add_category_data()
    {
        register_rest_field('project', 'category_data', ['get_callback' => array(
            $this,
            'get_all_category_data'
        ) , ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get all the category data
     *
     * @param $object
     * @param $field_name
     * @param $request
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_all_category_data($object, $field_name, $request)
    {
        return get_the_category($object['id']);
    }
}
```

I'd love to hear your ideas and thoughts on this. 
Thanks

Comment: edit your question to add the code you try to add a endpoint.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by that. This is all i have in my `functions.php`

Answer (score 6):

This code will add `categories_names` field to wp rest api response:

```
function wpse_287931_register_categories_names_field() {

    register_rest_field( 'project',
        'categories_names',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'wpse_287931_get_categories_names',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wpse_287931_register_categories_names_field' );

function wpse_287931_get_categories_names( $object, $field_name, $request ) {

    $formatted_categories = array();

    $categories = get_the_category( $object['id'] );

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $formatted_categories[] = $category->name;
    }

    return $formatted_categories;
}
```

Comment: thanks that did the job! I'd like to know what was wrong about my approach

Comment: Your code is not executing. I don't know from where you get this but looking at your code your are assuming that `init` method will be executed but is not.

Answer (score 5):

The same as above but replacing 'project' for **array('post')** should work.

```
function wpse_287931_register_categories_names_field()
{
    register_rest_field(
        array('post'),
        'categories_names',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'wpse_287931_get_categories_names',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'wpse_287931_register_categories_names_field');

function wpse_287931_get_categories_names($object, $field_name, $request)
{
    $formatted_categories = array();

    $categories = get_the_category($object['id']);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $formatted_categories[] = $category->name;
    }

    return $formatted_categories;
}
```